# PHP Convert delimited text file to XML

Tags: php, xml

I need some help converting a delimited text file into a usable XML file using PHP.

The text file itself consists of hundreds of airports and their respected runways; here's a small sample:

```
AP;KLAX;LOS ANGELES INTL;33.942495;-118.408070
RW;06L;33.949109;-118.431156
RW;06R;33.946853;-118.434239
RW;07L;33.935825;-118.419336
RW;07R;33.933645;-118.419014
RW;24L;33.950189;-118.401664
RW;24R;33.952100;-118.401945
RW;25L;33.937359;-118.382708
RW;25R;33.939553;-118.382906
AP;KSFO;SAN FRANCISCO INTL;37.618817;-122.375428
RW;01L;37.609453;-122.381897
RW;01R;37.607689;-122.380139
RW;10L;37.628739;-122.393392
RW;10R;37.626289;-122.393106
RW;19L;37.627342;-122.367111
RW;19R;37.626481;-122.370608
RW;28L;37.612095;-122.359264
RW;28R;37.613917;-122.358056
```

Basically, I need to parse this into a usable XML file in the following format:

```
<Airports>
    <Airport ID="KLAX" Name="LOS ANGELES INTL">
        <Location Lat="33.942495" Lon="-118.408070" />
        <Runways>
            <Runway>06L</Runway>
            <Runway>06R</Runway>
            <Runway>07L</Runway>
            <Runway>07R</Runway>
            <Runway>24L</Runway>
            <Runway>24R</Runway>
            <Runway>25L</Runway>
            <Runway>25R</Runway>
        </Runways>
    </Airport>
    <Airport ID="KSFO" Name="SAN FRANCISCO INTL">
        <Location Lat="37.618817" Lon="-122.375428" />
        <Runways>
            <Runway>01L</Runway>
            <Runway>01R</Runway>
            <Runway>10L</Runway>
            <Runway>10R</Runway>
            <Runway>19L</Runway>
            <Runway>19R</Runway>
            <Runway>28L</Runway>
            <Runway>28R</Runway>
        </Runways>
    </Airport>
</Airports>
```

Here's the PHP code I'm curing using:

```
$fp = fopen('data.dat', 'r');

$xml = new XMLWriter;
$xml->openURI('php://output');
$xml->setIndent(true);
$xml->startElement('Airports');

while ($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, ';'))
{
    if ($line[0] == 'AP')
    {
        $xml->startElement('Airport');
        $xml->writeAttribute('ID', $line[1]);
        $xml->writeAttribute('Name', trim($line[2]));

        // Location
        $xml->startElement('Location');
        $xml->writeAttribute('Lat', $line[3]);
        $xml->writeAttribute('Lon', $line[4]);
        $xml->endElement();

        $xml->startElement('Runways');
    }

    if($line[0] == 'RW')
    {
        $xml->startElement('Runway', $line[1]);
        $xml->endElement();
    }

    if($line[0] == 'AP')
    {
        $xml->endElement();
        $xml->endElement();
    }
}
$xml->endElement();
```

But this is what's being created:

```
<Airports>
 <Airport ID="KLAX" Name="LOS ANGELES INTL">
  <Location Lat="33.942495" Lon="-118.408070"/>
  <Runways/>
 </Airport>
</Airports>
<Airport ID="KSFO" Name="SAN FRANCISCO INTL">
 <Location Lat="37.618817" Lon="-122.375428"/>
 <Runways/>
</Airport>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`startElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-start-element.php) only takes one parameter, you probably want [`WriteElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-write-element.php) in that case.
Also your endElement for airport and runways is a bit off

```
$first = true;
while ($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, ';'))
{
    if ($line[0] == 'AP')
    {
        if (!first){
        // close the runway and airport tags
            $xml->endElement();
            $xml->endElement();
        }
        $xml->startElement('Airport');
        $xml->writeAttribute('ID', $line[1]);
        $xml->writeAttribute('Name', trim($line[2]));

        // Location
        $xml->startElement('Location');
        $xml->writeAttribute('Lat', $line[3]);
        $xml->writeAttribute('Lon', $line[4]);
        $xml->endElement();

        $xml->startElement('Runways');
        $first = false;
    }

    if($line[0] == 'RW')
    {
        $xml->writeElement('Runway', $line[1]);
    }
}
// close all open tags
while ($xml->endElement() !== false) { continue; }
```

Comment: Works like a charm; must simpler than I was making it out to be.